# Street address map plotting

Tags: r, geocoding

I have 30 thousand home addresses and want to geocode them (i.e., convert "123 ABC Street" to a latitude and longitude).

Researched to find if there is any good tool available, but very confusing.

Anyone can suggest any resource?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will get you one address from the Google Maps geocoding API:

```
geocodeAddress <- function(address) {
    base <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" 
    key  <- "your_google_maps_api_key_here"
    url  <- URLencode(paste0(base, address, "&key=", key))
    
    RJSONIO::fromJSON(url, simplify=FALSE)
}
```

And how to use it:

```
result <- geocodeAddress("1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043")
```

You can pull out just the lat and lng with, e.g.:

```
result_lat <- result$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
result_lng <- result$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng
```

For your 30k addresses, you can loop over them individually. More info available at [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). Last I checked, there are limits on the number of requests per second and total number of free requests per day, but I suspect the cost for 30k isn't very high.

Alternatively, you can upload data in csv format to UCLA's geocoder: [gis.ucla.edu/geocoder](https://gis.ucla.edu/geocoder).

A third alternative is to use Texas A&M's geocoder: [geoservices.tamu.edu](http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/BatchProcess/).

Comment: If my answer (or any other answer) solved your problem, please mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to the answer.  This is good practice so that answerers get rewarded for their efforts and so that other folks with the same question (who wind up on this page) can more-easily find a working answer.  More info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/400575).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest the free `tidygeocoder` package (https://jessecambon.github.io/tidygeocoder/).
2. Depending on the size of your data frame find my suggestion for parallelization: [Is it possible to parallelize the geocode function from the tidygeocoder package in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71560603/is-it-possible-to-parallelize-the-geocode-function-from-the-tidygeocoder-package/72729367#72729367)