# Is it possible to parallelize the geocode function from the tidygeocoder package in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to geocode a couple of addresses in R. I am working with the geocode function from the tidygeocoder package in R. To make it faster I'd love to parallelize this function, but I do not know how this might work.

I am working on Windows.

Here is an example:

| id | street | state | county |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 happiness | TT | South |
| 2 | 234 parallel | HH | North |

```
# create cluster
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(8, type = "PSOCK")

# geocode the addresses
latlon <- parallel::parLapply(cl=cl, geocode, .tbl = address_df, method = 'osm', lat = latitude , long = longitude, address = NULL, street = street, county = county, state = state)
```

street should be the list (is a column of ) I'm trying to run the parLapply function on and geocode the function. The geocode function does not let me use a vector for addresses. I have use all the options of geocode, street, county and state to get their latitude and longitude.

Is it possible to parallelize this function?

Answer (score 5):

**Original Data Extended**

I extended `address_df` by a real-world example:

```
address_df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                         street = c("123 happiness", "234 parallel", "60 E Broadway"),
                         state =  c("TT", "HH", "MN"),
                         county = c("South", "North", "Hennepin"))
```

**Packages and Purpose**

For iteration I generally like to work with the `purrr` package (https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) and for parallelization I suggest its extension, the  `furrr` package (https://furrr.futureverse.org/).

```
library(tidyverse) # includes purrr package
library(tidygeocoder)
# install.packages("furrr") # will also install `future`package
library(furrr)  # will also load `future`package
```

**Data Preparation**

Next to the `geocode()` function there is also the `geo()` function which only requires a comma-separated sting with a combined address as an argument, this is preferable for iteration, instead of `.tbl` and the arguments `street`, `state`, and `county` we will only need to pass one comma-separated address string.

```
address_df <- address_df %>% 
  mutate(address = paste(street, state, county, sep = ", "))
```

The iteration in `furrr` requires a list:

```
address_list <- address_df$address %>%
  as.list()
```

`address_list` now contains a list element for each comma-separated address sting.

**Preparation for Parallelization**

The `plan()` function from the `future` package (is installed and loaded with `furrr` package) defines how many cores you want to work on the parallelization, I usually chose `availableCores() - 1`

```
plan(strategy = "multisession", workers = availableCores() - 1)
```

**Parallel Iteration**

```
address_geodata <- future_map(.x = address_list, 
                              ~ geo(address = .x, method = 'osm', lat = latitude , long = longitude)) %>% 
  # puts the lists back together into a dataframe/tibble
  bind_rows()
```

**Join Original data and geo data**

```
address_df_geo <- address_df %>% 
                  left_join(address_geodata, by = "address")
```

[image: Outcome Data Frame]

address_df_geo